# Compiling a lambda expression results in delegate with Closure argument

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

When I use `Expression.Lambda( ... ).Compile()` in order to create a delegate from an expression tree, the result is a delegate of which the first argument is [`Closure`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.closure.aspx).

```
public static Func<T, T, T> CreateTest<T>()
{
    ParameterExpression a = Expression.Parameter( typeof( T ) );
    ParameterExpression b = Expression.Parameter( typeof( T ) );
    Expression addition = Expression.Add( a, b );

    return (Func<T, T, T>)Expression.Lambda( addition, a, b ).Compile();
}

...

// 'addition' equals
// Int32 lambda_method(
//     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,
//     Int32,
//     Int32 )
Func<int, int, int> addition = DelegateHelper.CreateTest<int>();
int result = addition( 5, 5 );
```

I can easily call the delegate through ordinary code without passing a `Closure` object, but where does this `Closure` come from?

How can I call this delegate dynamically?

```
// The following does not work.
// Exception: MethodInfo must be a runtime MethodInfo object.    
MethodInfo additionMethod = addition.Method;
int result = (int)additionMethod.Invoke( null, new object[] { 5, 5 } );
```

Using expression trees it looks like I have to pass the `Closure` object.

```
PropertyInfo methodProperty
    = typeof( Delegate ).GetProperty( "Method", typeof( MethodInfo ) );
MemberExpression getDelegateMethod
    = Expression.Property( Expression.Constant( addition ), methodProperty );
Func<MethodInfo> getMethodInfo
    = (Func<MethodInfo>)Expression.Lambda( getDelegateMethod ).Compile();
// Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method
// 'Int32 lambda_method(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure, Int32, Int32)'
Expression call
    = Expression.Call(
        getMethodInfo(),
        Expression.Constant( 5 ), Expression.Constant( 5 ) );
```

This is a simplified example which doesn't make sense in its own right. What I am actually trying to achieve is to be able to wrap e.g. `Func<Action<SomeObject>>` with `Func<Action<object>>`. I can already do this for non nested delegates. This is useful during reflection, [as discussed here](http://whathecode.wordpress.com/2011/07/02/casting-to-less-generic-types/).

How should I correctly initialize this `Closure` object, or how do I prevent it from being there?

Comment: @JonSkeet: I'll do my best, the problem is the total example is quite complex. I am attempting to call a previously compiled delegate recursively. While I try to extract a small subset of the problem, [here](http://pastebin.com/53f0VqnF) you can already find the entire function.

Comment: Yeah, making it shorter would certainly help :)

Comment: @JonSkeet: As a bit more information, the goal would be to allow creating wrapper functions so e.g. `Action<Action<SomeType>>` could be wrapped by `Action<Action<object>>`. This continues on [my previous implementation](https://github.com/Whathecode/Framework-Class-Library-Extension/blob/master/Whathecode.System/DelegateHelper.cs) which can only do this for `Action<SomeType>` to `Action<object>`.

Comment: You realize that's not type-safe, right? `Action<T>` is contravariant, but `Action<Action<T>>` is effectively covariant.

Comment: Yes I do, but I use it during reflection where I know the types correspond, but I don't want to know about the specific types so I can support any type. I blogged about it [in detail here](http://whathecode.wordpress.com/2011/07/02/casting-to-less-generic-types/).

Comment: @JonSkeet: I added a bit more info where I believe the problem lies. If it's still not clear it will have to wait until tomorrow when I have time to create a small example which compiles.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `Closure` type you see is an implementation detail. The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.closure.aspx) is pretty explicit about it:

> This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not
>   intended to be used directly from your code. Represents the runtime
>   state of a dynamically generated method.

An expression tree can have a state.

The Closure instance will contain all the non literal constants that the lambda expression, well, closes over. It can also contain a chain of delegates for nested lambdas in expression trees.

To achieve this, the expression tree compiler uses a cute little trick. It generates in memory code using a `DynamicMethod`, that is by definition static. Yet, they're creating a delegate that is [“closed over its first argument”](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.aspx). Meaning that the CLR will pass the target field of the delegate as a first argument of the static method, so you don't have to. Effectively hiding the Closure argument from you.

The solution to your problem is simple, don't try to call the method, invoke the delegate, either by using [Delegate.DynamicInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.dynamicinvoke.aspx) when you're using reflection, or [Expression.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355170.aspx) in the context of an expression tree.

Comment: This is great, thanks! My function was working recursively by calling itself with a new `MethodInfo`. I created a new one which accepts a delegate instead and uses `Expression.Invoke` to call it. After some major refactoring I'll commit the changes. I can now successfully wrap e.g. `Func<SomeType, Func<int>>` with `Func<SomeType, Func<EnumType>>`. Generic calculations with strong typed enums. :) Loving it. `IEnumerable<FlagsEnum> setFlags = EnumHelper<FlagsEnum>.GetFlaggedValues( flags );`

Comment: K, this is possible in .NET 4.0 using `Enum` as well, but I can use this 'delegate wrapper' in plenty of other scenarios. I did a short efficiency comparison with `Enum` and the difference is negligible.