# Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method. Expression.call(MethodInfo, Expression)

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

The following code does:

1. Creates a Lambda Expression
2. Compiles it to a method
3. Calls the method via Expression.Call

The [code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d51sd0)

```
public static void Main()
{
    ParameterExpression paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "arg");

    LambdaExpression lambdaExpr = Expression.Lambda(
        Expression.Add(
            paramExpr,
            Expression.Constant(1)
        ),
        new List<ParameterExpression>() { paramExpr }
    );

    Console.WriteLine(lambdaExpr);

    var method = lambdaExpr.Compile().Method;

    var expressions = new Expression[]
    {
        Expression.Constant(5)
    };
    Expression.Call(method, expressions);

}
```

The error

> Run-time exception (line 27): Incorrect number of arguments supplied
>   for call to method 'Int32
>   lambda_method(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure, Int32)'

Where did the System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure, come from?

How do I invoke this method using  Expression.Call?

I know there are other ways of achieving the same goal, like calling `lambdaExpr.Compile().DynamicInvoke()` but, due to constraints, I need to do it in the above way.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7940617/5740031) should help you.

Comment: If you're trying to create an expression that calls the lambda, is there any reason you don't just use `Expression.Call(lambdaExpr, ...)`? You talk about "due to constraints" but without saying what those constraints are (or the reason for them) it's hard to suggest alternatives.

Comment: `Expression.Call(method, expressions)` returns a MethodCallExpression, but you are ignoring it. Are you sure you are trying to do the right thing?