# When compiled, Lambda expression tree always adds System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees, cil

I'm performing various operations to uodate method behaviours at runtime using expression trees.

When done with compilation, I can have access to standard delegates, but the resulting MethodInfo (which I need to reflect again), always adds a parameter of type

```
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure
```

as first argument.

This is a simple example of the behaviour (we just make a wrapper to the function to call itself, it's useless on it's own except for explaining the issue).

```
class Program
{
    public static float SimpleOperation(float f1, float f2)
    {
        return f1 + f2;
    }

    public static LambdaExpression WrapSelf<TDelegate>(MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        var parameterInfoList = methodInfo.GetParameters();
        ParameterExpression[] wrappedParameters = new ParameterExpression[parameterInfoList.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < parameterInfoList.Length; i++)
        {
            var parameterInfo = parameterInfoList[i];
            ParameterExpression inputParam = Expression.Parameter(parameterInfo.ParameterType, parameterInfo.Name);
            wrappedParameters[i] = inputParam;
        }

        Expression funcCall = Expression.Call(methodInfo, wrappedParameters.ToArray());
        return Expression.Lambda<TDelegate>(funcCall, wrappedParameters);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MethodInfo methodToWrap = typeof(Program).GetMethod("SimpleOperation", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

        var lambdaExpression = WrapSelf<Func<float, float, float>>(methodToWrap);

        Func<float, float, float> wrappedAddDelegate = (Func<float, float, float>)lambdaExpression.Compile();


        MethodInfo resultMethodInfo = wrappedAddDelegate.Method;


        var info = resultMethodInfo.GetParameters()[0];

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

So now this all compiles correctly, and performing :

```
float f = wrappedAddDelegate(2.0f,3.0f);
```

returns 5 as expected

Now the issue is that resultMethodInfo now has 3 parameters (the first one being closure), so signature is now

```
(Closure,float,float) -> float
```

So if I try to use that method info for further reflection it tends to mess things up.

Is there's a way to perform the same task, but getting rid of the closure type in the result , so our method info should keep same signature eg :

```
 (float, float) -> float
```

I know it's definitely possible to perform this using Reflection.Emit instead, but would like to know it there is a solution using Expression tress only.

Comment: You could probably dig through the reference source to find an answer.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935306/compiling-a-lambda-expression-results-in-delegate-with-closure-argument

Comment: The Compile method is supposed to provide a callable delegate, not a dynamic method. The closure must be there to provide constant data in the expression and other things and cannot be eliminated from all methods. I suggest you modify your code to take the closure into account (and bind other methods to it if you need to).